# Lency issue with @HystrixCommand when doing the performance testing

Tags: spring-boot, hystrix

I am facing latency issue with @HystrixCommand method when doing the performance testing with multiple request.

the thread is waiting long on java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with execution.isolation.strategy SEMAPHORE in the @HystrixCommand. This configuration won't use hystrix's internal thread pool.